# zend 2 getting entity properties value without using in exchangearray() method

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am newbie to zend framewrok 2. I am just practicing album application provided by zf2 documentation. After that i create another controller namely PersonalInfo. In PersonalInfo entity i used a properties namely dt which will be not updated by form input. It is updated by default in database. Here is my Entity.

```
class PersonalInfo {
protected $id;
protected $name;
protected $fName;
protected $email;
protected $picture;
protected $dt;


public function exchangeArray($data) {
    $this->id = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
    $this->name = (!empty($data['name'])) ? $data['name'] : null;
    $this->fName = (!empty($data['fName'])) ? $data['fName'] : null;
    $this->email = (!empty($data['email'])) ? $data['email'] : null;
    $this->picture = (!empty($data['picture'])) ? $data['picture'] : null;

}

// Add the following method:
public function getArrayCopy() {
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function getFName() {
    return $this->fName;
}

public function setFName($fName) {
    $this->fName = $fName;
}

public function getEmail() {
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email) {
    $this->email = $email;
}

public function getPicture() {
    return $this->picture;
}

public function setPicture($picture) {
    $this->picture = $picture;
}
public function getDt() {
    return $this->dt;
}

public function setDt($dt) {
    $this->dt = $dt;
}
```

I am strange if i not use $this->dt= (!empty($data['dt'])) ? $data['dt'] : null; in exchangeArray method then getDt() method return null but if i use that in exchangeArray method than it returns actual data. In my general understanding i am not clear about the trick of exchangeArray method. It is neccessary to know for me because in future to solve this type of problem.

Comment: With reference to the documentation, `exchangeArray()` method is basically shown to be used for setting the $_POST values to the object  properties. (Note: not necessary to be post values always).

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable you'll notice that all this information is defined in your factory

```
'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
    return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
}
```

The part of interest in the definition is the `new ResultSet()` and the `setArrayObjectPrototype()` method

If you take a look at `\Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet` you'll see that the `exchangeArray` method is required -> https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/ResultSet/ResultSet.php#L65

The reason for that requirement is because, as you iterate over your result set, the `ResultSet` itself clones your prototype, and then calls `exchangeArray` which effectively 'hydrates' your object with row data ->  https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/ResultSet/ResultSet.php#L105

So, in summary, when used in the above manner if you don't explicitly set all your properties in the `exchangeArray` method, they will always remain null when fetched from the db.